# tabto-like functionality within TOC line

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm currently trying to create a list of entries (content not important for this) within a document, using `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}` to add a line in the TOC for each entry.

Now, each line in the TOC should not contain only the name of the entry, but also 2 or 3 extra pieces of information to serve as a quick-reference in addition. While I could just add them with some fixed spacing, due to unequal word lengths it'd look like a mess. Instead I'd want basic tabulator functionality such that the terms are placed neatly below each other in the TOC.

Here's an idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

TOC

> ```
> 1. Chaptername
> E1Info1         E1Info2       E1Info3      E1Info4................Pg#
> Entry2Info1aaa  E2Inf2        Entry2Info3  E2Inf4.................Pg#
> Testname        5             None         Rring..................Pg#
> ```

And so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=.5cm, bottom=.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\entry}[5]{
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1 #2 #3 #4}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXR}
\textbf{#1} & Karmakosten: #2 & Limitierungen: #3 & #4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\medskip

\noindent
#5
\medskip

\hrule}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Testsection}
\entry{E1Info1}{E1Info2}{E1Info3}{E1Info4}{Foo}
\entry{Entry2Info1aaa}{E2Inf2}{Entry2Info3}{E2Inf4}{Bar}
\entry{Testname}{5}{None}{Rring}{Testtext}
\end{document}
```

The line of contention is that `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1 #2 #3 #4}`; I need to find a way to separate the 4 entries such that independently of the word length of the previous term the next term will begin at a specific point, so that e.g. all `#2` terms in the TOC are neatly one under the other. The issue is that the means I'd usually use for such alignment problems (tabular or tabto) don't play nicely within the `\addcontentsline` command.

Comment: @cfr "Don't write it to another file and then read it back. What's the purpose of that?" I...literally have no idea what you're talking about. I'm using the TOC because I still utilize its section and, well, "tell me the page this entry is on" functionality. The only difference is that instead of \subsection{something something} I use the \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection{something something} function because I don't actually want any subsection headers in my list of entries. The issue would be the same. I figured utilizing this would be easier than implementing a wholly new TOC.

Comment: @cfr I'm not. The \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{xyz} just tells the TOC to create a new subsection entry with the label xyz using itself as reference point. As far as the TOC is concerned, it works the same as \subsection{xyz}. The difference is that the latter also creates a subsection header with the same text in the body of the document. My issue and the topic of the question now is with formatting said label.

Comment: Probably I'm just confused then. (I guess I don't understand the `p.77` given the output you're showing. But likely my brain is just fried.

Comment: @cfr Hm...yeah, I probably shouldn't have used that for the example. Basically I'm putting together a compendium of entries from multiple books. The page number placed there is its location within the original text, not the page it appears in my document. I'll put in something less confusing, sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should have figured that out. Fried brain only partially functional, I think. Something less confusing might head off similar comments from other fried brains, though.

Comment: @jfbu Fixed. Well, it doesn't remain true, it became true again when I added the other two entries to stay consistent with the formatting example I put above it. #5 is just any old text as seen in the command. Sorry; I kept forgetting to add it because it's not that important to the question itself (I guess I should've just removed the whole document body part of the entry-command for a truly minimal mwe, but it felt like it provided a bit of context.

Comment: by using `\addcontentsline` without real `\subsection` you are going to confuse hyperref both for the hyperlinks in the TOC and for the PDF bookmarks.

Comment: @jfbu I see...I guess solving that would be stuff for another question. Then again, I mostly put in the hyperref as QoL, it's not particularly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeing close to the posted MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=.5cm, bottom=.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{%
                      \noindent #1\tab #2\tab #3\dotfill #4\par}}}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXR}
\textbf{#1} & Karmakosten: #2 & Limitierungen: #3 & #4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\medskip

\noindent
#5
\medskip

\hrule}


\begin{document}
\NumTabs{4}
\tableofcontents

\section{Testsection}
\entry{E1Info1}{E1Info2}{E1Info3}{E1Info4}{Foo}
\entry{Entry2Info1aaa}{E2Inf2}{Entry2Info3}{E2Inf4}{Bar}
\entry{Testname}{5}{None}{Rring}{Testtext}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Remarks:

- the TOC looks about like what is expected but in real life you want hyperlinks. This is possible e.g. using `\label/\ref` perhaps by helping `\label` with some `\phantomsection`. But the provided info is too scarce.
- clearly the method is questionable because it adds data to the toc file which will make it to all TOCs in document, if there is more than one. But some important info and how concretely the data is included in document and hence how one can refer to it is lacking.
- there is clearly something wrong with the document body, each `\entry` doing its own tabularx. As this seems other problem than the one asked I left as in MWE.